# Implementing a lock screen for iOS app

Tags: ios, storyboard, appdelegate

I'm working on an app which needs a 'lock screen' where the user has to enter a password to access the data stored in the app.

This lock screen should be shown whenever the app ist being started and after a few minutes of  user inactivity.

Currently I have a separate UIViewController in my storyboard which isn't connected to any other views in the storyboard. I understand I can access this view controller by sending instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier to [self storyboard]. Hoewever this doesn't work from the app delegate.

But I need to call the lock screen from the app delegate before the app delegate tries to open the database.

What would be a good way to implement this?

Comment: There are several [passcode screen libraries on github](https://github.com/search?l=Objective-C&q=passcode&ref=commandbar). Give some of them a try.

Comment: Thanks for the tip! I actually had implemented the lock screen itself already, just wasn't sure how to access it, but I figured it out now.

Answer (score 4):

This is probably a late answer but I had to implement the same requeriment for one of my customers using Storyboard. [You can download the full project from here](http://www.4shared.com/zip/OIAfZ8Ny/Lockview.html). Hopefully this might help someone.

I created two Viewcontrollers, one which is the MainView and the other which requires a four-digit code to be dismissed. I created a modal segue between the MainView and the BlockKeypadViewController and named it "lockItSegue". 
On the MainView I inserted a RoundRectButton which calls the "lockIt" method.
The method just perform the segue "lockItSegue".

```
- (IBAction)lockIt:(id)sender 
{
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"lockItSegue" sender:self];
}
```

On the BlockKeypadViewController.h, I created

```
//
//  BlockKeypadViewController.h
//  Consultablet
//
//  Created by EDGARD AGUIRRE ROZO on 22/03/13.
//  Copyright (c) 2013 Colombia Creative Software. All rights reserved.
//

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>

@interface BlockKeypadViewController : UIViewController
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *wrongCodeLabel;//*codigoIncorrectoLabel;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *tryAgainLabel;//*trateNuevamenteLabel;

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *digit1;//*caracter1;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *digit2;//*caracter2;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *digit3;//*caracter3;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *digit4;//*caracter4;
@property int counter;//contador;
@property int codeIn;//claveIngresado;
@property int unlockCode;//claveDesbloqueo;
-(void) calculate:(int)number;//calcular:(int)numero;
- (IBAction)one:(id)sender;//uno:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)two:(id)sender;//dos:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)three:(id)sender;//tres:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)four:(id)sender;//cuatro:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)five:(id)sender;//cinco:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)six:(id)sender;//seis:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)seven:(id)sender;//siete:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)eight:(id)sender;//ocho:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)nine:(id)sender;//nueve:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)zero:(id)sender;//cero:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)cancel:(id)sender;//cancel:(id)sender;
-(void)checkCode;//verificarClave;

@end
```

On the BlockKeypadViewController.m:

```
//
//  BlockKeypadViewController.m
//  Consultablet
//
//  Created by EDGARD AGUIRRE ROZO on 22/03/13.
//  Copyright (c) 2013 Colombia Creative Software. All rights reserved.
//

#import "BlockKeypadViewController.h"
@implementation UILabel (My2)
//- (void)setImage:(UIImage *)image forState:(UIControlState)state animated:(BOOL)animated
- (void)setHidden:(BOOL)hidden animated:(BOOL)animated
{
    //[self setImage:image forState:state];
    [self setHidden:hidden];
    if (animated)
    {
        CATransition *animation = [CATransition animation];
        [animation setType:kCATransitionFade];
        [animation setTimingFunction:[CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut]];
        [animation setFillMode:kCAFillModeBoth];
        [animation setDuration:.3];
        [[self layer] addAnimation:animation forKey:@"UILabelSetAnimationKey"];
    }
}
- (void)setHidden:(BOOL)hidden animated:(BOOL)animated seconds:(int)seconds
{
    //[self setImage:image forState:state];
    [self setHidden:hidden];
    if (animated)
    {
        CATransition *animation = [CATransition animation];
        [animation setType:kCATransitionFade];
        [animation setTimingFunction:[CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut]];
        [animation setFillMode:kCAFillModeBoth];
        [animation setDuration:seconds];
        [[self layer] addAnimation:animation forKey:@"UILabelSetAnimationKey"];
    }
}
@end
@interface BlockKeypadViewController ()

@end

@implementation BlockKeypadViewController
@synthesize digit1,digit2,digit3,digit4,counter,codeIn,unlockCode,wrongCodeLabel,tryAgainLabel;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.counter = 1;
    self.codeIn=0;

    self.unlockCode=1234;
    NSLog(@"Unlock Code %d",self.unlockCode);

    [digit1 setHidden:YES animated:YES];
    [digit2 setHidden:YES animated:YES];
    [digit3 setHidden:YES animated:YES];
    [digit4 setHidden:YES animated:YES];
}
-(void)checkCode
{
    if(self.codeIn==self.unlockCode)
    {
        [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
    }
    else
    {
        [wrongCodeLabel setHidden:NO animated:YES seconds:.1];
        [tryAgainLabel setHidden:NO animated:YES seconds:.1];
        [self.digit1 setHidden:YES animated:YES];
        [self.digit2 setHidden:YES animated:YES];
        [self.digit3 setHidden:YES animated:YES];
        [self.digit4 setHidden:YES animated:YES];
        self.codeIn = 0;

        NSLog(@"Wrong Code");
    }
}
- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
}
-(void) calculate:(int)number
{
    if(self.counter==1)
    {
        [wrongCodeLabel setHidden:YES animated:YES seconds:.2];
        [tryAgainLabel setHidden:YES animated:YES seconds:.2];
        [self.digit1 setHidden:NO animated:YES];
        self.codeIn = number*1000;
    }
    if(self.counter==2)
    {
        [self.digit2 setHidden:NO animated:YES];
        self.codeIn = self.codeIn+number*100;
    }
    if(self.counter==3)
    {
        [self.digit3 setHidden:NO animated:YES];
        self.codeIn = self.codeIn+number*10;
    }
    if(self.counter==4)
    {
        [self.digit4 setHidden:NO animated:YES];
        self.codeIn = self.codeIn+number;
        [self performSelector:@selector(checkCode) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.2];
    }
    if(self.counter<4)
    {
        self.counter++;
    }
    else
    {
        self.counter=1;
    }
}
- (IBAction)one:(id)sender
{
    [self calculate:1];
}
- (IBAction)two:(id)sender
{
    [self calculate:2];
}
- (IBAction)three:(id)sender
{
    [self calculate:3];
}
- (IBAction)four:(id)sender
{
    [self calculate:4];
}
- (IBAction)five:(id)sender
{
    [self calculate:5];
}
- (IBAction)six:(id)sender
{
   [self calculate:6];
}
- (IBAction)seven:(id)sender
{
    [self calculate:7];
}
- (IBAction)eight:(id)sender
{
    [self calculate:8];
}
- (IBAction)nine:(id)sender
{
    [self calculate:9];
}
- (IBAction)zero:(id)sender
{
    [self calculate:0];
}
- (IBAction)cancel:(id)sender
{
    [self.digit1 setHidden:YES animated:YES];
    [self.digit2 setHidden:YES animated:YES];
    [self.digit3 setHidden:YES animated:YES];
    [self.digit4 setHidden:YES animated:YES];
    self.codeIn = 0;
    self.counter = 1;
}


@end
```

Answer (score 0):

To present the lockVC on top of your HomeVC from your appDelegate, use this :

```
UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard" bundle:nil];
HomeVC *hvc = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"HomeVC"];
self.window.rootViewController = hvc;
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

LockVC *lvc = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"LockVC"] 
[self.window.rootViewController presentViewController:lvc animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Comment: I'm afraid that doesn't work. I get this warning and the lock screen doesn't show up:

'Warning: Attempt to present <LockscreenViewController: 0x7475a70> on <UINavigationController: 0x746d070> whose view is not in the window hierarchy!'

Comment: This warning comes because you can't display a modal view controller from the appDelegate. You need to display a modal ViewController from whichever viewController is currently displaying full-screen. So you should first set a window.rootViewController in your appDelegate and then call this code from that controller.

Comment: Note that I've edited my answer so that the warning doesn't come, but I still don't recommend doing this, you should present Lock screen from within your viewControllers instead of didFinishLaunching:

Comment: Ok I understand. So basically, my app delegate launches the navigationcontroller, which again presents the first view controller. From this view controller I can present this modal lock screen. Then I just need to find a way for the app delegate to wait within didFinishLaunching until the user has entered the password in the lock screen. Maybe I could move the code to check the password and open the database into a separate method in the app delegate (not didFinishLaunching) and call this method from the lock screen?

Answer (score 0):

There is not need (and I actually do not recommend to use it for this porpoise) to use the `AppDelegate` to implement this or any `LockScreen` solution. You should create a segue from the `RootViewController` to the `LockScreen` and name it as you want (e.g. `lockItSegue`). Then from the button action call `[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"lockItSegue" sender:self];`
On the logic (`BlockKeypadViewController.m`) of the `LockScreen` (once the user has entered the correct code), call `[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];`